# refactor methods which use reflection

Tags: go, reflection, refactoring

Suppose I have two struct which are

```
type A struct {
}

func (a *A) SomeFunc (s string) {
    // some codes
}

func (a *A) ProcessRequest(funcName string, parameters map[string]*structpb.Value) error {
    ...
    if method := reflect.ValueOf(a).MethodByName(funcName); method.IsValid()
    ...
        values := make([]reflect.Value, 0)
        ...
        rv := method.Call(values)
        ...
}

type B struct {
}

func (b *B) AnotherFunc (i int) {
    //somecode
}
```

and I am using reflection to call methods in A which is `SomeFunc` and it is working well.

Now I need to write a struct B which also has `ProcessRequest` which has exacly same code with the one in A.

Is there anyway I can refactor this?

I have tried to create

```
type ProcessProvider struct{
}
```

and let A and B embed it but when the method is called, *ProcessProvider is passed as the receiver and it cannot find `SomeFunc` and `AnotherFunc`.

An interface

```
type ProcessProvider interface {
    ProcessRequest(serviceName string, parameters map[string]*structpb.Value) error
}
```

is helpful but I still have to copy paste the code.

Comment: Write the function `ProcessRequest(recv any, funcName string, parameters map[string]*structpb.Value) error { ... if method := reflect.ValueOf(recv) ...}`.  Call that function from the methods on types A and B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `ProcessRequest` have to be a member of those structs?

If there is no such a requirement you can disconnect this method from structs and accept structs as an argument.

```
func ProcessRequest(a any, funcName string, parameters map[string]*structpb.Value) error {
    ...
    if method := reflect.ValueOf(a).MethodByName(funcName); method.IsValid()
    ...
        values := make([]reflect.Value, 0)
        ...
        rv := method.Call(values)
        ...
}
```